# JavaScript form validation onsubmit

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to validate this form before it is submitted to the order form page using `onsubmit` event, but it's not working.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Also, how do I submit the product(s) selected with price and product ID on to an order form page?  I need to use form controls to allow the user to put in personal and billing info (name, address, etc.) Any help with this would be appreciated.

Here's my code I'm trying to validate with `onsubmit`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <title>Javascript - Shopping Cart</title>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function checkCheckBoxes( ) {
            if (document.frmTest.product1.checked == false &&
                document.frmTest.product2.checked == false &&
                document.frmTest.product3.checked == false &&
                document.frmTest.product4.checked == false)
                    {
                    alert ('You must select a product to continue.');
                    return false;
                    }
            else
                    {
                    return true;
                    }
        }
    </script>
    
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Shopping Cart - Product Page</h1>
    
    <form name="product" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return checkCheckBoxes( );" >
        
        <div id="product1">     

            <p id="title1"><b>Desktop Computer</b></p>

            <img src="images/desktop.jpg" alt="desktop" width="100"/>
            
            <p>The latest in desktop computing.</p>

            <p><input type="checkbox" name="product1" id="001">Price $599.99</p>     

        </div>

        <div id="product2">

            <p id="title2"><b>Monitor</b></p>

            <img src="images/monitor.jpg" alt="monitor" width="100"/>

            <p>21 inch monitor</p> 

            <p><input type=checkbox name="product2" id="002">Price $159.99</p>
        </div>

        <div id="product3">

            <p id="title3"><b>Keyboard</b></p>

            <img src="images/keyboard.jpg" alt="keyboard" width="100"/>

            <p>USB Keyboard</p> 
            
            <p><input type=checkbox name="product3" id="003">Price $39.99</p>           
        </div> 

        <div id="product4">

            <p id="title4"><b>Mouse</b></p>

            <img src="images/mouse.jpg" alt="mouse" width="100" />

            <p>USB Keyboard</p> 

            <p><input type=checkbox name="product4" id="004">Price $25.99</p>
            </p>
        </div>

        <br />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" onClick="cart()";/><input , type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset">
    
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am having trouble understanding this due to grammar mistakes and asking multiple things. Please edit your post and clarify what the issue is.

Comment: "Weston Probst - Javascript Lab 7" ??? Is this your HOMEWORK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your if statement to use getElementById. I ran your code, but instead used the if statement:

```
if ( (document.getElementById("001").checked == false) &&
    (document.getElementById("002").checked == false) &&
    (document.getElementById("003").checked == false) &&
    (document.getElementById("004").checked == false))
```

and it worked.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was missing!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<form name="product"
```

to

```
<form name="frmTest"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you install a debugger like Firebug, you can call

```
checkCheckBoxes( );
```

manually in the console (without submitting the form), so that you can see the error messages generated by the function, which in this case is

```
TypeError: document.frmTest is undefined
```

Since the name of the form is "product", "document.frmTest..." should probably be called "document.product..." instead.