# Form submission checkscript() javascript

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I want to be able to submit the form only if the 'my val 2' option is selected. If another option is selected and the submit button is pressed, I want it to just say they cannot submit it. Also, if they submit it, I want it to go to a submission page that says what they submitted. Here is my form:

```
<form action="formSub.php" method="POST" name="myform" onsubmit="return checkscript()">
            <select name="test_select">
                <option value="1">my val 1</option>
                <option value="2">my val 2</option>
                <option value="3">my val 3</option>
                <option value="4">my val 4</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="test_button" onClick="submitform(test_select.value)">
        </form>
```

Here are my javascript functions

```
function submitform(val) {
    var obj = val;;
    alert("Value =  " + obj);
}

function checkscript() {
    if (obj !== "2") {
        alert('This is not \'my val 2\' so you cannot submit');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also, my checkscript function doesn't work correctly. The f statement is always false.

Comment: You need to learn JavaScript basics about scopes. A local variable from one function is not available in another function.

Comment: Thanks I realized that after I tried why that wasn't working. I just didn't know what to put there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have mistake in your script. JavaScript not see variable obj in scope of function checkscript(). You rather try to declare that variable as global variable. You have examples how to validate forms here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp
and also : [Javascript form validation onsubmit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711175/javascript-form-validation-onsubmit)
as @Noob UnChained write you must get value from the field by script. Also you have function `submitform(val)`

As I see that function gets the value from the select panel. So you can try use that function to return selected value from the list.

```
var obj;
function submitform(val) {
    obj = val;
    alert("Value =  " + obj);
}

function checkscript() {
    if (obj !== "2") {
        alert('This is not \'my val 2\' so you cannot submit');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

For the first function `submitform()` set variable obj and second function use set obj to check value.

But if I were you I would use the method @Noob UnChained because it's simpler and also you can validate many forms in one function. 
Also try to read JavaScripts tutorials to write good scipts.

I hope that help you.